# Can$A \cap (B' \cap C')$ be $(A \cap B') \cap (A \cap C')$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, boolean-algebra

If I use the above statement, provided that it is right, in a question, would I have to prove it as well?

Comment: It is correct, and whether you'd "have to prove it" depends of course on context.

Comment: I'm assuming $A'$ refers to the complement of $A$.  Yes, your statement is correct.  Whether or not you might have to prove something like that depends on your teacher/text, but I would suspect that a statement to that effect exists.

Comment: In particular, you could "prove the statement" using the commutativity/associativity of the operation $\cap$ (and of course using $A \cap A = A$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the proof is rather trivial: since the $\cap$ operator is both associative and commutative, all the following are equivalent:
$$ (A \cap B) \cap (A \cap C) $$
$$ A \cap B \cap A \cap C $$
$$ A \cap A \cap B \cap C $$
$$ A \cap B \cap C $$
$$ A \cap (B \cap C) $$

As others said, whether or not you actually have to include the proof is mostly a matter of context.

Answer (score 1):

Statement: $A \cap (B' \cap C') = (A \cap B') \cap (A \cap C')$

- $A \cap (B' \cap C') \subset (A \cap B') \cap (A \cap C')$

$x \in A \cap (B' \cap C') \implies x \in A$ and $x \in B' \cap C' \implies x \in A, x \in B', x \in C' \implies x \in A \cap B'$ and $x \in A \cap C' \implies x \in (A \cap B') \cap (A \cap C')$

- $(A \cap B') \cap (A \cap C') \subset A \cap (B' \cap C')$

You can do it similarly.